# How do i open videos with VLC with just double-clicking?

Tags: vlc

I know it's possible to open a file with Vlc by right clicking and then clicking "Open With Other Application" and then Vlc, but double clicking a file doesn't work and instead opens "Videos". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to right click on the file, choose "Open with other Application", and then choose VLC from the list provided:

[image: Select Application]

If the application you want to use is not in the "Recommended Applications" list, click on "View All Applications" and then you should see "VLC media player" so long as it is installed on your system. This works on a per-file-type basis, much like it does in other operating systems.

Another option would be to set VLC as default for video in the "Default Applications" section of the Settings application:

[image: Settings - Default Applications]

Here you can set the applications that you would like for specific mime groups. This will override any file-specific rules you may currently have in place, though.

Hope this gives you what you need.

Comment: i wanted it so every time i double click a video file it always opens with VLC?

Comment: Updated answer to include a second option, which may be a little too broad a solution for  most people.

Answer (score 0):

In "Settings - Default Applications", you can set VLC Media Player as the default application for video files. That will cause video files to open by default with VLC.

In general, to open a particular file type by default with a specific application, e.g. an `.mp4` file with VLC, right-click such file in Files, and on the "Open with" tab, select the application.
[image]

Double-clicking then will always open with that application.

At any time, you can, for one time, choose another application using the "Open With Other Application" in the right-click menu.